# Whatsapp floating Button Colour HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a floating WhatsApp button to my website by using Kevin Castro's Pen here: https://codepen.io/demoonkevin/pen/MvPEpV

```html
* WhatsApp Button */

.whatsApp{
    position:fixed;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:40px;
    background-color:#25d366;
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    z-index:100;
}
.my-whatsApp{
    margin-top:16px;
}
```

But when I use it on my website it taking my wordpress website global color which is yellow and I want it to be white even tho I add color:#FF it is still same as you can see in screenshot  [Here is the colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQAUa.png)

Comment: add !important near .whatsApp css --> **color: #FFF !important;**

Comment: no problem bro and it helps me too